# Is there a bloom option in blender 2.77?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, lighting

I switched to Blender 2.77 because it's easier to make materials in my opinion. I tried to do some rendering but I can't find a bloom option anywhere. I tried searching everywhere but there's no information either. I'm using the Eevee render engine.

Comment: I don't think Eevee existed before Blender 2.8 so please check which version you're actually using.

Comment: Hey, so sorry i got them confused, im using the default "Blender Render"

Comment: No problem, but best to get it right! 2.77 is a bit before my time, but there seems to be a 2013 bloom tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/MOhrbq-7ocU?t=22).

Comment: Thank you very much!